# Chrome not rendering specific font-size for SVG text element inside clipPath set as objectBoundingBox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg, clip-path

I just discovered clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" and it is working out as expected for the most part.

However, Chrome is not behaving when a text element is included as part of the clipping mask and the font-size is set at or below 0.5. Using font-sizes greater than 0.6 work as expected.

This codepen should work correctly in Firefox, but will fail in Chrome, unless you adjust the font-size to .6 or greater.
http://codepen.io/jasonpearson/pen/rLGGEZ

Am I missing a webkit prefix on something? I don't see this particular issue on http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

```
<style>
  * { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
  svg { border: 1px solid red; }
  .clipped-container { width: 500px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid green;}
  .clipped { width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: green; -webkit-clip-path: url('/#clipper'); }
</style>

<svg width="500px" height="200px">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <text x="0" y=".8" font-size=".6" textLength="1">Hola</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y"0" width="500px" height="200px" fill="red" clip-path="url(#clipper)"></rect>
</svg>

<div class="clipped-container">
  <div class="clipped"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: A tool you will find useful http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug. [I have reported it on your behalf.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=626936)